# Match values in pandas dataframe and replace with matched values from master table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to match and replace values from Main Table to detail in Mapping Table without using for-loop.

Main Table:

| Case | Path1 | Path2 | Path3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | c | d |
| 2 | b | c | a |
| 3 | c | a | e |
| 4 | b | d | e |
| 5 | d | b | a |

Mapping Table:

| factor | detail |
| --- | --- |
| a | sample A |
| b | sample B |
| c | sample C |
| d | sample D |
| e | sample E |
| f | sample F |

I would like the output to be like this.

Result:

| Case | Path1 | Path2 | Path3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sample A | sample C | sample D |
| 2 | sample B | sample C | sample A |
| 3 | sample C | sample A | sample E |
| 4 | sample B | sample D | sample E |
| 5 | sample D | sample B | sample A |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
# df -> main table
# dmap -> map table

cols = df.filter(like='Path').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(dmap.set_index('factor')['detail'])
print(df)

# Output
   Case     Path1     Path2     Path3
0     1  sample A  sample C  sample D
1     2  sample B  sample C  sample A
2     3  sample C  sample A  sample E
3     4  sample B  sample D  sample E
4     5  sample D  sample B  sample A
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by all columns without first - if no match get `NaN`s:

```
df1.iloc[:, 1:] = df1.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: x.map(df2.set_index('factor')['detail']))
```

Or [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) - if no match get original value:

```
df1.iloc[:, 1:] = df1.iloc[:, 1:].replace(df2.set_index('factor')['detail'])
print (df1)
   Case     Path1     Path2     Path3
0     1  sample A  sample C  sample D
1     2  sample B  sample C  sample A
2     3  sample C  sample A  sample E
3     4  sample B  sample D  sample E
4     5  sample D  sample B  sample A
```

If want update only columns starting `Path` use [`Series.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html) with [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df1.update(df1.filter(regex=r'^Path').replace(df2.set_index('factor')['detail']))
print (df1)
   Case     Path1     Path2     Path3
0     1  sample A  sample C  sample D
1     2  sample B  sample C  sample A
2     3  sample C  sample A  sample E
3     4  sample B  sample D  sample E
4     5  sample D  sample B  sample A
```